# Is the replacement theorem true for conditionals?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

I read about the replacement theorem in Kleene's intro to logic which is as follows:

If $\vDash(A\sim B)$ then $\vDash(C_A\sim C_B)$ where $C_A$ is a formula containing formula $A$ and $C_B$ is obtained by replacing $A$ with $B$ in $C_A$.

My question is :

Is the same true for $\supset$ (conditional operator) that is

$\vDash(A\supset B)$ then $\vDash(C_A\supset C_B)$. The reason I think this might be true is shown in my work below. If it is or isn't can you please proof it. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\bot$ be your favourite contradiction, and let $B$ be a propositional variable.

Then $\vDash \bot \supset B$ (a contradiction materially implies anything).

But not $\vDash \neg\bot \supset \neg B$ (a tautology doesn't fix that $B$ is false!).

So that gives a counterexample to your conjecture (with the context $C$ being simply constructed by taking the negation).

Exercise: where does your reasoning fail, applied to that example?

Comment: I see I didn't consider cases with negations. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Smith points out, the answer is no.

However, there does exist a meta-theorem which allows for replacement with conditionals which allows for replacement of a sort depending on where the subformula you replace appears.

For more details, see the following site and the referenced papers:

http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/concepts/semi/index.html

http://users.clas.ufl.edu/jzeman/modallogic/chapter02.htm [see the section on the semisubstitutivity of implication]

http://home.utah.edu/~nahaj/logic/concepts/semi/example.html